# Iterate through column, subtract the content of each cell with a certain amount and store the result in the same cell

Tags: applescript

I am try to open a Pages document.
But it doesn't let me open a Pages file, the files are all greyed out.
What I want to do after is iterate through all the cells of Column "C" of the first table and then subtract from its content a certain amount and of course save the result in the same cell.
This is what I am writing but I am not sure since I have started yesterday learning applescript.

```
  tell application "Pages"
    activate
    try
        set the chosenDocumentFile to ¬
            (choose file of type ¬
                {"com.apple.iwork.pages", ¬
                    "com.microsoft.word.doc", ¬
                    "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document"} ¬
                    default location (path to documents folder) ¬
                with prompt "Choose the Pages or Microsoft Word document to open:")
        open the chosenDocumentFile
    on error errorMessage number errorNumber
        if errorNumber is not -128 then
            display alert errorNumber message errorMessage
        end if
        
        tell the first table of chosenDocumentFile
            repeat with i from 2 to count of cells of column "C"
                set the value of cell i of column "C" to... #don't know how to subtract an amount and then store the result
            end repeat
        end tell
        
    end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beforehand, in a separate script, get the type idenitifer for a pages doc (I'm using v7, dunno if it makes a difference). Not sure why it's necessary but getting the type identifier is a two-step process. Essentially, without the sffpages as part of your string, you were also filtering out all pages docs.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set pgsF to ((path to documents folder) & "sam.pages" as text) as alias
    -- or…
    -- set pgsF to (choose file)
    set infor to info for pgsF
    set ti1 to type identifier of infor
    --> "com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages"        
end tell
```

We can put that into a new applescript like this:

```
set ti1 to "com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages"
tell application "Pages"
    activate
    set cdf to choose file of type ti1 with prompt ¬
    "Choose the Pages or Microsoft Word document to open:"
    open cdf
    
    tell page 1 of document 1
        
        set cc to column "C" of table 1
        set cColc to cells 2 thru -1 of cc whose value is not missing value
        set cColv to value of cells 2 thru -1 of cc whose value is not missing value
        
        repeat with fc in cColc
            set value of fc to (value of fc) - 2
        end repeat
        
    end tell
end tell
```

If the cells of column "C" *always* have a value in them, then you could likely dispense with the 'whose value is not missing value' sequences. There isn't any error handling so for example, if you have non-numeric data in column "C", an error will result.

You may need to set the table's 'Object Placement' to 'Stay on Page' (select the table then `View > Show Arrange Tools > Object Placement`, or from the Inspector's `Arrange` tab) before you can work with the table in an applescript. If not set, you may get an error like this: `Pages got an error: Can’t get table 1 of page 1 of document 1. Invalid index.`

Updated: Now filtres out a 1-row header. By editing the '2' or the '-1', more header rows can be excluded.

Comment: I get the error "Can’t make \"Cosin\" into type number." number -1700 from "Cosin" to number. "Cosin" is basicay the column "C". Maybe because it starts from the title of the column which of course is not an integer?

Comment: Yeah, that would be the likely culprit. If that's an issue then the 'ccol' lines will need to filtre out the header line.

Comment: Give this a try. It now affects only those rows from 2 onward. This can be edited. FYI, it can be helpful if a representative data sample is included in the question along with such details. On another note, from the script's perspective, the numbers are real, not integer (e.g. class of value of cell 2 of column "C" of table 1 --> real). I think that's how Pages stores them but I'm guessing.

Comment: Works great! :)